# Exceção no Filter de Apenas uma página

Tags: java, jsp, filter

Tenho um filter @WebFilter("/*") que bloqueia tudo, porém, eu gostaria que tivesse exceção de algumas páginas...

Uma página (ou que eu escolhesse) não fosse bloqueada

Tem como?

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/retiro","/valor","/pessoa","/gasto","/desistente","/total","/usuario","/imprimir","/pagamento"})



 public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req  = ((HttpServletRequest)request);
        HttpServletResponse res  = ((HttpServletResponse)response); 
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        // String usuario = String.valueOf(session.getAttribute("login"));


         if(session.getAttribute("login") != null){
             //((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestDispatcher("/index").forward(req, res);
            // res.sendRedirect("index");
             chain.doFilter(request, response);
         }else{
             ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestDispatcher("/index").forward(req, res);
            // res.sendRedirect("index");
         }

        //chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Atualmente estou usando, assim

Comment: Tem, fazendo [na unha](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125315/4056678) no seu filtro ([outro exemplo aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31327972/4056678)). Se a dúvida é "`@WebFilter` tem um atributo para excluir determinados padrões de URLs?" ou algo do tipo, (ainda) não **:)**

Comment: Poste o código do seu filtro. Assim fica mais fácil de mostrar o que pode ser mudado nele para permitir as exceções que você quer.

Comment: já.. mas não tenho ideia de como fazer, estou estudando a sugestão do @Renan

Comment: postei.. assim eu pego todas as minhas servlets, mas querias colocar todas ter exceção de uma ex; logar